# Tie-breaking in PuLP optimization

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

**Story**

I'm trying to write a baseball elimination problem using the PuLP (python) minimization. The basic problem looks like this:

[image]

Basically `x_ij` is the future wins of team `i` over team `j`, `g_ij` is the overall games left between teams `i` and `j`, `k` is the team we're interested in, `p_j` is the points a team has so far. Variable `z_j` is just auxiliary, it's `1` when team `j` is ahead of `k` (by total wins) and `0` if behind.

**Problem**

I have no problem writing this in terms of PuLP and solving the optimization problem. However, I wanted to add some tie-breaking rules, to adjust the constraints, so that if, e.g., `t_j == t_k`, it compares, lets say, `x_jk` with `x_kj` to decide whether team `j` is ahead of `k`.

**Question**

So basically I need a condition that kicks in only under particular circumstances. Is there a way to do this easily in PuLP? Maybe by introducing some other variable? If not, what module/method would you suggest to solve this kind of tie-breaking thing?

Comment: Do the t variables take integer values? If so you could add a fractional component derived from the tiebreak rules. Then the fractional component would only matter if the t variables would otherwise be tied

Comment: I thought of it, but the problem is there are a whole bunch of tie-breaking rules, so this will quickly escalate and kill our numerical algorithm. That's why I asked if there is a more rigorous way.

Comment: When you say numerical algorithm do you mean the pulp solver? I'd be surprised if my suggestion tremendously affected the speed.

Comment: Well, the tie-breaking rules are really different (there are like 16 of them), so you can't just hardcode all of them into the different fractional orders.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of tie breaking rules that compete with each other, you may need a more complicated objective function that rewards or penalizes certain teams according to the tiebreak rules. You will need to somehow "price" the conditions using the objective function. Dummy variables and Big M constraints may be helpful for "if/then" conditions